# How can I display (echo/print) the currently set error reporting level in PHP?

Tags: php, error-reporting

I am working on a rather large project (multiple teams) so I don't have complete control over the code.  Unfortunately, error_reporting is changed in many places throughout the code.  When I get to a certain point in the code, I want to see what error reporting is currently set to.  Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

http://www.php.net/error_reporting

`int error_reporting ([ int $level ] )`

> Returns the old error_reporting level or the current level if no level
>   parameter is given.

You could also use examples provided by the link in order to cast the level (which is returned as integer) into the string. For example:

```
function error_level_tostring($intval, $separator = ',')
{
    $errorlevels = array(
        E_ALL => 'E_ALL',
        E_USER_DEPRECATED => 'E_USER_DEPRECATED',
        E_DEPRECATED => 'E_DEPRECATED',
        E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR => 'E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR',
        E_STRICT => 'E_STRICT',
        E_USER_NOTICE => 'E_USER_NOTICE',
        E_USER_WARNING => 'E_USER_WARNING',
        E_USER_ERROR => 'E_USER_ERROR',
        E_COMPILE_WARNING => 'E_COMPILE_WARNING',
        E_COMPILE_ERROR => 'E_COMPILE_ERROR',
        E_CORE_WARNING => 'E_CORE_WARNING',
        E_CORE_ERROR => 'E_CORE_ERROR',
        E_NOTICE => 'E_NOTICE',
        E_PARSE => 'E_PARSE',
        E_WARNING => 'E_WARNING',
        E_ERROR => 'E_ERROR');
    $result = '';
    foreach($errorlevels as $number => $name)
    {
        if (($intval & $number) == $number) {
            $result .= ($result != '' ? $separator : '').$name; }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

use it as `echo error_level_tostring(error_reporting(), ',');`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 10):

Use `error_reporting()` with no parameters.  It will return the current error level.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php